# I have one problem with '/' xslt

Tags: xml

I have one problem with '/'
we have a field which contains multiple values and these values will come separated by a slash '/'.
Now I don't know how to resolve when the values it self contains a '/'.
For eg.

`<xsd:Value> Tiger / Lion / Deer</xsd:Value>`----This is what is expected and when we tokenize it using '/' we can get value as Tiger , lion and deer.

But what if Tiger value is changed to 'Ti/ger'?
How to escape this slash char in xslt?

Answer (score 1):

In attribute or text values, the slash is just a regular a regular character and does not need escaping, like in

```
//city/zoo[@name='Ti/ger']
```

In element and attribute names, [slashes are not allowed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-NameStartChar).

Comment: <xsl:variable name="value1" select="tokenize($value ,'/')"/>
<xsl:for-each select="$value1" >
      
  <xsd:code>
 <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </xsd:code>
</xsl:for-each>

Here value is coming as 'Tiger / Lion / Deer'

now if values is like 'Ti/ger / Lion / Deer' ,Then there are 4 split instead of 3 (expected)

Comment: @user696172 Looks like you're looking for `tokenize($value, ' / ')` then.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an XML/XSLT problem. The delimiter (separator character) cannot appear in the values that it is supposed to delimit. You must somehow escape the delimiter when the value is constructed, and unescape it when the value has been extracted. Compare this with how markuop characters, '<', '>', etc must be escaped when they appear as character data in XML, or how special characters must be escpaed (encoded) when they are part of a URL.

However, considering your example, the delimiter might not be just the SLASH, but SPACE SLASH SPACE.

Comment: Hi all, thnks for ur help.@ Per Norman could you please elaborate on ur suggestion (ompare this with how markuop characters, '<', '>', etc must be escaped when they appear as character data in XML, or how special characters must be escpaed (encoded) when they are part of a URL.)as the delimiter could be any thing slash or SPACE SLASH SPACE.